# python3 import not finding module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to test out an example from a book and I'm getting an `ImportError`.

The example starts out like:

```
from tkinter import *
from PP4E.Gui.Tools.widgets import frame, button, entry
```

And if I put an `import sys; print(sys.path)` at the beginning of the code, the output is

```
['/Users/aaa/Documents/workspace/programming-python/PP4E/Lang/Calculator', 
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-12.2-py3.4.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py3.4.egg',
 '/User/aaa/Documents/workspace/programming-python',... ]
```

This is what a truncated version of my `programming-python` directory looks like:

```
❯ tree
.
├── PP4E
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── Gui
│   │   ├── Tools
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── widgets.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── Lang
│   │   └── Calculator
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── calc0.py
└── site-packages
    └── PP4E.pth
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
❯ python3 calc0.py                                                            

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calc0.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PP4E.Gui.Tools.widgets import frame, button, entry
ImportError: No module named 'PP4E'
```

Does anybody know what I have to do to get Python to find the PP4E module? Thanks.

Comment: Try looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python) answer.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, my PYTHONPATH environment variable is already set (which is where the fourth string in that `sys.path` array comes from). Also, all of my directories have an `__init__.py` file in them, which I thought would fix the problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: can't you just add the directory to the path variable? Have a look at [this](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469160-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-)

Answer (score 5):

I had my `PYTHONPATH` wrong -- the root directory is `/Users`, not `/User`. Thanks.